# Improving a page to warn users about the impending closure of a service

Tags: user-communication

We are currently rolling out a new remote access solution (based on the Citrix ICA protocol) to replace the current remote access solution which has been around for a few years (based on a Java platform and uses the Microsoft RDP protocol for connectivity) across our organisation.

As we near the end of our migration efforts, we are really struggling to increase user engagement with the product despite marketing it to the different business engagement managers. We are able to track who has logged onto the service from reports being generated from the Citrix backend and we are seeing a less than 15% usage (approx 800 users over 7000 user base).

What internal marketing techniques can we use to aggressively market the new technology to different users? We have thought about sending weekly spreadsheet updates containing user activity logs to each line of business manager to ramp up the interest in the product, but is there anything else we can do?

We have been working to migrate users across to this new service but the general uptake has been slow, and one of our goals is to increase user activity on the new service.

Below you will find the sample of an alert message that is going up on the page of a remote access service we have been working to replace.

I don't think is effective because it does not incite the user to take action about migrating to the service (especially if the user has already migrated across). It seems to be more informational rather than striking me as a notice that will inspire users to take action.

How can we improve it to make it more effective and generate interest/activity in the new service?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, nothing in the notice indicates that the old product will cease working at any point in the future.

Second, you need a call to action. The current call to action is "Please contact your local service desk." which is ineffective as you've surmised.

In the ideal case, you'd want to put a dialog in front of the user when they first log in or start up the software, where the default option will upgrade them to the new product. Assume that 98% of your users won't read more than 10 words of the dialog, too. Users by nature would rather click Cancel every day for the next 20 years than navigate a setup page. So, that means this upgrade needs to be one-click; if they have to go through anything more than a EULA to switch, they're going to back up and then click Cancel every time the dialog comes up again.

Pick good default options for everything so the user doesn't *have* to make a choice unless they want to.

Once they upgrade, you'd want to point them to the new product any time they try to use the old one. Still let them into the old one, but make it easier to get into the new one than to keep using the old one.

If your only option is an email to users, you want to do as close to the same thing as possible. Put together an email with a clear call to action, and make the process of upgrading as simple and easy as possible.

The general principle is this: If you want to get users to follow a specific path, make that path the easiest and simplest choice. If you want them to avoid a path (feature, product, etc), make it harder for them to follow.